# Compilation fails with generics in the iOS part of a Kotlin Multiplatform project

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, generics, kotlin-multiplatform

I've configured my first KMM project and I've started sharing code between my apps.
In my shared kotlin code, I have the following function:

```
class ListStorage() {
   fun <T : Storable>registerList(): StoredList<T> {
        return StoredList()
    }
}
```

`Storable` is a simple interface

```
interface Storable {
    var id: String
}
```

And `StoredList` is defined as a generics class:

```
class StoredList<T : Storable>
```

Then in my iOS project I'm trying to call my first function:

```
let houses: StoredList<House> = self.storage.registerList()
```

This unfortunately fails to compile:

> Cannot assign value of type 'StoredList' to type
> 'StoredList'

Here is the House implementation in the iOS project:

```
class House : Storable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
}
```

I have no issue if I define `House` and call my `registerList` function all in the shared module. Any idea? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: what does `self.storage.registerList()` return ?

Comment: It's actually the first line of code of the question: a `StoredList<T>`

Comment: And what is `self.storage`? `registerList()` looks to be defined as a plain function so it shouldn't be possible to call it with `self.storage` as receiver... are you sure there are not two definitions of `registerList()`?

Comment: @SimonJacobs Sorry for the confusion, wanted to make it short but it's a function of the Storage object. I edited the question.

Comment: KMP generics have limited support on iOS side, check out [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html#generics) for details